# Scaling an Axon application - command handling load tests failing

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, cqrs, event-sourcing, axon

I've created Axon application with two Spring Boot services - `hotel-booking-command` and `hotel-booking-query`, for command side and query side respectively. These services are partially and loosely based on [the sample application provided by AxonIQ](https://github.com/AxonIQ/hotel-demo). I'm using Axon Server as an event store and message router. The services are hidden behind Spring Cloud Gateway. I'm using Consul as a discovery service. Everything seems to work fine, as long as I use only one instance of the command side application. When I'm using 2 or more instances and the load gets higher, connection to the Axon Server is being lost on all instances:

```
2022-06-26 17:00:37.675  INFO 86356 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] o.a.m.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor    : [AddRoomCommand] executed successfully with a [Integer] return value
2022-06-26 17:00:37.675  INFO 86356 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] o.a.m.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor    : Dispatched messages: [RoomAddedEvent]
2022-06-26 17:01:10.258  INFO 86356 --- [SQ-P024.local-0] i.a.a.c.impl.AxonServerManagedChannel    : Unable to recover current connection to AxonServer. Attempting to reconnect...
2022-06-26 17:01:10.264  INFO 86356 --- [SQ-P024.local-0] i.a.a.c.impl.AxonServerManagedChannel    : Requesting connection details from localhost:8124
2022-06-26 17:01:15.272  WARN 86356 --- [SQ-P024.local-0] i.a.a.c.impl.AxonServerManagedChannel    : Connecting to AxonServer node [localhost:8124] failed.

io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: deadline exceeded after 4.997735389s. [closed=[], open=[[buffered_nanos=4998488350, waiting_for_connection]]]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:262) ~[grpc-stub-1.43.0.jar:1.43.0]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:243) ~[grpc-stub-1.43.0.jar:1.43.0]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:156) ~[grpc-stub-1.43.0.jar:1.43.0]
    at io.axoniq.axonserver.grpc.control.PlatformServiceGrpc$PlatformServiceBlockingStub.getPlatformServer(PlatformServiceGrpc.java:250) ~[axonserver-connector-java-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at io.axoniq.axonserver.connector.impl.AxonServerManagedChannel.connectChannel(AxonServerManagedChannel.java:115) ~[axonserver-connector-java-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at io.axoniq.axonserver.connector.impl.AxonServerManagedChannel.createConnection(AxonServerManagedChannel.java:335) ~[axonserver-connector-java-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at io.axoniq.axonserver.connector.impl.AxonServerManagedChannel.ensureConnected(AxonServerManagedChannel.java:308) ~[axonserver-connector-java-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at io.axoniq.axonserver.connector.impl.AxonServerManagedChannel.lambda$scheduleConnectionCheck$4(AxonServerManagedChannel.java:378) ~[axonserver-connector-java-4.5.4.jar:4.5.4]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2022-06-26 17:01:15.272  INFO 86356 --- [SQ-P024.local-0] i.a.a.c.impl.AxonServerManagedChannel    : Failed to get connection to AxonServer. Scheduling a reconnect in 2000ms
2022-06-26 17:01:15.272  INFO 86356 --- [SQ-P024.local-1] i.a.a.c.impl.AxonServerManagedChannel    : Connection to AxonServer lost. Attempting to reconnect...
2022-06-26 17:01:15.273  INFO 86356 --- [SQ-P024.local-1] i.a.a.c.impl.AxonServerManagedChannel    : Requesting connection details from localhost:8124
2022-06-26 17:01:20.275  WARN 86356 --- [SQ-P024.local-1] i.a.a.c.impl.AxonServerManagedChannel    : Connecting to AxonServer node [localhost:8124] failed: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: deadline exceeded after 4.988964197s. [closed=[], open=[[buffered_nanos=4989266439, waiting_for_connection]]]
2022-06-26 17:01:20.275  INFO 86356 --- [SQ-P024.local-1] i.a.a.c.impl.AxonServerManagedChannel    : Failed to get connection to AxonServer. Scheduling a reconnect in 2000ms
```

The logs from Gatling very quickly start to look like this (250 requests per second were executed, the code of the Gatling simulation is available [here](https://github.com/a-glapinski/event-sourcing-and-cqrs-jvm/blob/api-testing/gatling/src/gatling/scala/simulations/HotelBookingCommandSimulation.scala)):

```
for HTTP POST "/api/hotel-booking/command/rooms"

io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Operation timed out: /192.168.0.12:8082
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/api/hotel-booking/command/rooms" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946) ~[na:na]
```

Usually, only the first 500 or 1000 requests are handled correctly.

Current version of the application (including load tests, located in `gatling` module) is available here: https://github.com/a-glapinski/event-sourcing-and-cqrs-jvm/tree/api-testing. I'm willing to provide more details about the application if needed; now I'm not sure what can be wrong and where to look at.

Is there something that is potentially missing in configuration of my Axon command side application? Should I change some configuration in Axon Server? Or maybe the concept of the whole system I've created is wrong in the context of Axon Framework and my application won't be able to scale at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for sharing your project. It is an amazing initiative!

I have a couple of concerns about this design on the strategic level:

- 1. `implementation("org.axonframework:axon-spring-boot-starter")`,
     `implementation("org.axonframework.extensions.springcloud:axon-springcloud-spring-boot-starter")`
     are used together to distribute commands. There is no
     need for this. Axon Server acts as a service registry and discovery for your commands. It will route commands to appropriate command handlers (much better then Consul).
- 2. If you really need to use Consul/Eureka as
     service discovery, my advice is to limit Consul to only discovering
     Web components/Controllers, not Axon Command handlers (let Axon
     Server do that).

This implies

- removing `springcloud:axon-springcloud-spring-boot-starter` as a
  first step. You do not need two mechanisms (Consul, AxonServer) for service discovery and message/command routing.
- potentially extracting web components (controllers) so
  they can be load balanced and discovered separately from the deep
  decision-making components like Aggregates (command handling
  components). Please notice, that this will fall back to just a regular Spring Boot configuration of Consul (no need for `springcloud:axon-springcloud-spring-boot-starter` on this level).

It would be nice to see the result of the same test without Gateway and Consul at first. In this case, you should be able to identify the bottleneck in a better way.

Comment: Removing `springcloud:axon-springcloud-spring-boot-starter` did indeed help. After this change there are no errors during load tests. Thanks a lot! The only thing that left me wondering is the _potentially extracting web components [...]_ bullet point. Could you elaborate more on that, please? I'm not sure if I understood correctly - did you mean to separate controllers and logic with `ReactorCommandGateway` from the aggregates implementation by creating another Spring Boot service?

Comment: When it comes to the result of the test without Gateway and Consul - not sure if I'm doing everything correctly (I only started to learn how to use Gatling), but I get similar errors as in the question. Maybe I'm not sending requests interchangeably in a correct way to the first and second instance of the `hotel-booking-command` service to manually "load balance" requests. Regardless of that, by sending requests through Gateway, everything works fine now.

Comment: Maybe this should be another question (I can create it), but I do wonder how could I check if by adding new instances of command and query services I would be able to increase the load without affecting response times. Basically, I would like to find out, whether or not by doubling the number of instances and by doubling the number of requests per second at the same time, I would still get the same response times as in the beginning. Is it something that is theoretically possible with the architecture of my application? I would need to deploy the application on several machines, I suppose?

Comment: I'm glad that it helped. To elaborate, yes you can extract your web controllers as separate service(s) to scale them independently of your domain components (aggregates, event handlers). This is not mandatory, but it is nice to know that you can do this. Eureka/Consul could be used to discover and load balance only these web components now (not Domain components - axon server will do that).  This is enabled by `location transparency` in Axon Framework - the Command dispatching component does not know the location of the handling component.

Comment: I advise adding an axon-micrometer extension to your axon applications. This way you can observe how fast your handlers are processing/handling messages (commands/events/queries). You can track this very granularly, per message type, so you can find the problematic/slow command/event handler method in your components. https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/monitoring-and-metrics#micrometer . Gatling seems to be a good tool for load and performance testing. Metrics is going to be a key in identifying how to scale up/scale out your applications.

Comment: axon.metrics.auto-configuration.enabled=true

axon.metrics.micrometer.dimensional=true

management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true

management.metrics.export.prometheus.enabled=true

management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled=true

Comment: If you are using Grafana to visualize metrics, this dashboard might help https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/14315